# GNU Grub error 2.2, frozen on my PC

Tags: grub

getting Grub error 2.2, but it will not let me add text, nor does it give me the F2. In fact it is frozen on my screen/PC

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.